# Add a post to custom post types category in wordpress from the front end (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, categories

I have been pulling my hair out over this one for a while now... time to ask for help:

I am using a front end form on a WordPress website.  The form will post to a Custom Post Category, attaching an image, tags and placing into the correct category.

Everything works well, except the category is not added to the post and I have NO IDEA why not.  I have read the codex over many times and several other forum tutorials but still no dice.

I am correctly pulling the category ID from a dropdown (I know from simply echoing the value )

Here is what I have.

Part of the Form:

```
<label for="category">Type:</label>
<select tabindex="10" class="postform" id="category" name="category">
<option value="35" class="level-0">cat1</option>
<option value="36" class="level-0">cat2</option>
</select>

...

<input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

The php

```
if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) &&  $_POST['action'] == "new_post") {

    // Do some minor form validation to make sure there is content
    if (isset ($_POST['offender_ign'])) {
        $title =  $_POST['offender_ign'];
    } else {
        echo 'Please enter the In Game Name (IGN) of the offender';
    }
    if (isset ($_POST['description'])) {
        $description = $_POST['description'];
    } else {
        echo 'Please enter some notes about the hate speech';
    }

    $tags = $_POST['post_tags'];
    $cat = $_POST['category'];

    // ADD THE FORM INPUT TO $new_post ARRAY
    $new_post = array(
    'post_title'    =>  $title,
    'post_content'  =>  $description,
    'post_category' =>  $cat,            //Not in an array as pulled from drop down  
    'tags_input'    =>  array($tags),
    'post_status'   =>  'pending',           // Choose: publish, preview, future, draft, etc.
    'post_type' =>  'product'  //'post',page' or use a custom post type if you want to
    );

    wp_set_post_categories($pid, $_POST['category'] );

    //SAVE THE POST
    $pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);

             //SET OUR TAGS UP PROPERLY
    wp_set_post_tags($pid, $_POST['post_tags']);

    // Image handling
    if ($_FILES) {
    foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
    $newupload = insert_attachment($file,$pid);
    // $newupload returns the attachment id of the file that
    // was just uploaded. Do whatever you want with that now.
    }
}
```

Any Pointers would be greatly appreciated... or even just a sanity check! Thanks

Comment: Have you tried changing this line `'post_category'=>$cat,` to this `'post_category'=>array($cat),` as it seems much like the tags, it is expecting an array rather than a single value. Also please include a print of both `$cat` and `$tags`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I did originally have 'post_category' => array($cat).  But see that there is only one value coming from the selection box so no need for an array.

$tags = $_POST['post_tags'];
     $cat = $_POST['category'];
     echo $tags;
     echo $cat;

Will echo: 
36 (the id),
tag1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer after a bit of playing:

In particular, note the change of name to be unique (not category but report-cat, the cpt was report in this case).

Then the lines to set post tags and post terms.  They must come after the setting the pid (as ziad-saab rightly pointed out, thanks).

Finally, the code to choose the category via drop down needed changing also.  This way no array was needed to pass the category as it is handled with the str replace function on the form. This also allow for multi select options if wanted.

```
                $select_cats = wp_dropdown_categories( array( 'echo' => 0, 'taxonomy' => 'report-cat', 'hide_empty' => 0 ) );
                $select_cats = str_replace( "name='cat' id=", "name='cat[]' id=", $select_cats );
                echo $select_cats;
```

_

```
if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) &&  $_POST['action'] == "new_post") {

    // Do some minor form validation to make sure there is content
    if (isset ($_POST['offender_ign'])) {
        $title =  $_POST['offender_ign'];
    } else {
        echo 'Please enter the In Game Name (IGN) of the offender';
    }
    if (isset ($_POST['description'])) {
        $description = $_POST['description'];
    } else {
        echo 'Please enter some notes about the hate speech';
    }

    $tags = $_POST['post_tags'];
    $post_cat = $_POST['cat'];

    // ADD THE FORM INPUT TO $new_post ARRAY
    $new_post = array(
    'post_title'    =>  $title,
    'post_content'  =>  $description,
    'post_category' =>   $post_cat,
    'tags_input'    =>  array($tags),
    'post_status'   =>  'pending',              // Choose: publish, preview, future, draft, etc.
    'post_type'     =>  'report',               //'post',page' or use a custom post type if you want to
    'taxonomy'      => 'report-cat'  
    );

    //SAVE THE POST
    $pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);

    //SET OUR TAGS AND CATEGORIES UP PROPERLY
    //wp_set_post_terms( $pid, $_POST['post_tags'], 'report-tag', false );
    wp_set_post_tags($pid, $_POST['post_tags']);

    wp_set_post_terms( $pid, $_POST['cat'], 'report-cat', false );

    // Image handling
    if ($_FILES) {
    foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
    $newupload = insert_attachment($file,$pid);
    // $newupload returns the attachment id of the file that
    // was just uploaded. Do whatever you want with that now.
    }
}


    //REDIRECT ON SAVE
    $link = "/success";
    //wp_redirect( $link );

} // END THE IF STATEMENT THAT STARTED THE WHOLE FORM



//POST THE POST YO
do_action('wp_insert_post', 'wp_insert_post');
```

Have a good read through here if you get stuck...I found the answer on one of the posts at the bottom (thanks to fitoussi)
http://voodoopress.com/how-to-post-from-your-front-end-with-no-plugin/#div-comment-716

Answer (score 0):

Simply move the line

```
wp_set_post_categories($pid, $_POST['category'] );
```

and put it below the line

```
$pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);
```

You're trying to use `$pid` when it's not yet available.

Comment: Nice idea but no joy.  I am now thinking that it must be something to do with the category setup.  I notice that sometimes when I set up a new custom post type the categories for that post type are either the same as the categories for the standard post types OR they are a post type specific category.  Not sure what defines what?